# UICollectionView min spacing not followd

Tags: ios, layout, uicollectionview

I am explicitly setting the minimum cell spacing in the Storyboard to be 4, and the Storyboard's layout shows this:
[image: Interface Builder screenshot]

But at runtime the vertical spacing is zero. (I have verified that the squares are still real squares.)

[image]

This has me losing hairs.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem and was able to figure out what was going on.

If you are programmatically setting the size of the cells, make sure that the size of those cells is also updated in the collectionview of Storyboard.... Once these two places where the cells match, then the spacing can be created correctly.

Chances are the space[image: These are greater than the cell size you set programmatically] is different because your cell width and height are greater in storyboard.